# Why is there a colon in some Programs between 2 statements

Tags: basic, qb64

I was going through a QB64 tutorial and saw the following program structure for printing numbers from 1 to 10 →

```
FOR x = 1 to 10: PRINT x: NEXT x
```

I have never seen such a kind of QB64 program. What do those colons `:` mean? Are they anything different?

Comment: Can't you just google this? I've already found something that looks useful here http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/Colon

Comment: Using the colon as a statement separator in MS-derived BASICs has been standard since at least the late '70s; I recall doing this on Apple II Integer BASIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the `QB64` IDE, you do not need to terminate statements using a special character like in other languages. This also means that you **CANNOT** expand a statement into multiple lines. Consider the following `IF...THEN...ELSE...` code block.

```
IF 
x = 1 
THEN
'Do something
...
```

This wouldn't be interpreted, as each new line terminates the statement. The above code would be parsed as:

```
Statement 1: IF [Incomplete Statement]
Statement 2: x = 1 [assign value 1 to x]
Statement 3: THEN [No such statement]
...
```

This means that you **must** constrain a single statement over a single line.

However, on the contrary, you ***are*** allowed to use *multiple* statements on a single line. In this case, since statements cannot be terminated with new lines, you **must** terminate them with a colon <kbd>:</kbd>. In your case,

```
FOR x = 1 to 10: PRINT x: NEXT x
```

This would be parsed as:

```
Statement 1: FOR x = 1 to 10 [Initialize a value and set a condition for a FOR...NEXT loop]
Statement 2: PRINT x [Print the value]
Statement 3: NEXT x [Close the FOR...NEXT code block, and iterate the variable]
```

There is no significant difference between using a colon or a new line for termination, but personally, I would recommend using new lines as they make the code considerably cleaner to look and easier to read. However, at times when there are multiple short and less important statements one after the other, you can combine them on a single line with colons to make your code shorter and concise to look.